# Происхождение фамилии Айвазовский.

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Фамилия нашего известного художника звучит красиво и несколько необычно. А каково её происхождение?

Comment: Это имеет отношение к вопросу или просто пофлудить?

Answer (score 2):

Да ничего особо "красивого" в ней нет. 
Фамилия армянского происхождения, предки хужожника были выходцами из Армении, носившими обычную армянскую фамилию Айвазян (Хайвазян). После переселения в Варшаву отец художника переписал фамилию на польский манер - Гайвазовский.

См. [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%98%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)
//----
Случайно обратил внимание, что в армянском варианте фамилии художника даётся написание Այվազովսկի (Айвазовски), думаю это неправильно, тем более, что у его брата Габриела - Հայվազյան ([haйвазян]).

Comment: Ну, насчет "нет ничего красивого" — это субъективно. Для Вас нет, а для автора вопроса есть.

Comment: Я в кавычки поставил.
А, я понял, в чем красивость. )))
Айву напоминает.)))

Answer (score 0):

У моец подруги муж - выходец из Дагестана по имени Айваз. Так что, думаю, это не только армянское имя, но вообще распространенное на Кавказе.

Comment: Про Дагестан, ге в каждом селе свой язык, говорить трудно Айваз имя чисто армянское. Среди некоторых народ дагестана распрострянен обычай давать детям имена друзей,  в т.ч. и других начциональностей.

Answer (score 0):

Айваз - персидское имя, означает - помощник;
Казым Айваз (тур. Kazım Ayvaz); 10 марта 1938, город Ризе, Турция — турецкий борец греко-римского стиля, чемпион Олимпийских игр, двукратный чемпион мира.

Comment: Да, но Айвазовский был этническим армянином. Сомнительно.